# What is "ANSI C++"?

Tags: c++, standards, c++98

I've had someone tell me that C++98 was written under ANSI before being formally standardised as ISO/IEC 14882:1998.

I know that ANSI was involved with C, but I can't seem to find much in the way of proof that the phrase "ANSI C++" is terribly accurate.

- Is "ANSI C++" a good description for C++98?
- Is "ANSI C++" a good description for subsequent versions of the C++ standard?

Comment: Hard to pick an answer to this question. Glad to see that it's attracted all the n0k-ers. :)

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I think I'm satisfied. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Initially, in '89, the standardization of C++ was handled by ANSI X3J16. Starting in '91 ISO WG21 joined in. You may want to read BS's [A History of C++: 1979-1991](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242787160_A_history_of_C_1979-1991). IMO, "ANSI C++" is just a leftover name; the language is "ISO C++" even though ANSI is indirectly involved in the standardization.

Answer (score 6):

This [gotw page](http://www.gotw.ca/iso/) describes the relationship of ANSI and ISO as far as C++ is concerned, briefly:

> The official names of the ISO and U.S. committees are:
>
> ISO/IEC JTC1/SC22/WG21 - C++ (ISO C++ committee)
>
> INCITS PL22.16 - C++ (the U.S. C++ committee, often called the "ANSI C++ committee" -- although more accurately INCITS is a separate organization that is not a part of ANSI but is accredited by ANSI to develop U.S. standards) (previously called X3J16 and J16)
>
> These two groups together are often referred to in the singular as "the C++ committee" because they meet and do their work together. The meetings are always in the same room at the same time

It sounds like the ISO standard developed by this committee automatically becomes the U.S. standard, although I am sure people who actually work in those committees can explain better.

Comment: In most countries, an ISO standard automatically becomes a national standard (or a standard of the national body, depending on how things are organized in the country).  Thus, ISO C++ is also ANSI C++, BSI C++, DIN C++, etc.  Conventionally, when it is an ISO standard, we call it ISO, rather than changing the name according to the country we're in.

Answer (score 2):

Sort of, but not really. There isn't, and never has been a separate ANSI standard for C++.

The current standard, however, is actually [INCITS/ISO/IEC 14882-2003](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS/ISO/IEC%2014882-2003). As of 2003, INCITS became a separate ANSI-accredited organization. The name INCITS wasn't new, but previously, it had been part of ANSI. In 2003, it was "[spun off](http://www.ansi.org/news_publications/news_story.aspx?menuid=7&articleid=331)" as a separate (but still ANSI-accredited) organization. The current (2003) standard therefore shows up as an INCITS/ISO/IEC standard, and I believe the upcoming (2011) standard will also.

Comment: ... and I always thought it was BS/ISO/IEC 14882:2003 ;-) .

Comment: @Charles: Close, but not quite. There's small difference: it's `BS ISO/IEC 14882-2003`. I'm not entirely sure how much the space vs. slash means though. My point wasn't so much to give INCITS credit or anything like that though, but to point out that "ANSI" isn't mentioned at all and INCITS is now a separate organization from ANSI. http://shop.bsigroup.com/en/ProductDetail/?pid=000000000030116778

Answer (score 2):

C++98 was developed by an international committee, part of the International Organization for Standardization (ISO). ANSI, and other national standards bodies, are members of this committee. The international standard has been adopted by ANSI as the US national standard, and likewise by many other national standards bodies.

Earlier versions were developed commercially in the US by AT&T; I'm not sure whether or not ANSI was involved in intermediate versions (EDIT: but Erik's answer suggests that it was, briefly).

> Is "ANSI C++" a good description for C++98?

I would call it "Standard C++", or "C++98", or just "C++" if it's clear that I'm talking about the current standard. While technically accurate, "ANSI C++" might confuse people who don't realise that it means the same thing, particularly people from other countries who might not know what ANSI is. I would probably get odd looks if I called it "British Standard C++", an equally accurate description.

> Is "ANSI C++" a good description for subsequent versions of the C++ standard?

Same answer. The C++ standards are developed by ISO, and adopted by ANSI and other bodies.

Comment: Or vice versa: the original C standard was ANSI C 1989.  Adopted by ISO in 1990, it became (with different paragraph numbers, but otherwise the same) ISO C 1990.  The C++ standard was ISO from the start, however.

Comment: @James: indeed, C's standardisation followed a different route. When I said "the standards" in the last sentence, I meant the C++ standards, not international standards in general.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK when they say "ANSI C++", they really mean "no compiler-specific extensions".

Comment: Right, but that says nothing about how accurate it is.

Answer (score 1):

The ISO working party creates the standard. C++98 had a lot of work done on standardisation in America (because that's where C++ was created, and where its creators lived) before the standardisation was taken under the auspices of the ISO committee (who were the same people). The final ISO Standard was then adopted by ANSI, and other national standards authorities.

I've always referred to Standard C++ as "Standard C++".

Comment: Bjarne is Danish/British and C++ was created for his PhD thesis, which he wrote in England. He didn't move to the States until later.