# how to use more precision in c++

Tags: c++, precision, pi, long-double

Hi i have built an algorithm to calculate pi but i use long float for it so i just get 3.14159 as a result, i need more precision. How?
here is the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  long double a, l, p, pi, r;
  long long int n, m;
  r = 100000;
  a = r * sqrt (3) / 2 ;
  n = 100000;
  m = 6;
  while (n > m)
  {
    a = sqrt (r / 2 * (r + a));
  m = m * 2 ;
  }
  l = sqrt (4 * (pow (r, 2) - pow (a, 2)));
  p = m * l;
  pi = p / (2 * r) ;
  cout << pi << endl;
  cout << "number of corners used: " << m << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

By the way there is a 24 core (12 dual core nodes) supercomputer at my high school, just in case

Comment: If your algorithm for computing pi needs a 24-core supercomputer, you're doing it wrong. Additional cores wouldn't even help here since you're not using threads.

Comment: Well, one way to get better precision (and in constant time) would be: `cout << M_PI;`.

Comment: If your ambition is to calculate decimals of pi you may consider using some kind of integer array to store the decimals. This will of course require some modification to your algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's more precision in that number than you're displaying. You just have to ask for it:

```
cout << std::setprecision(40) << pi << endl;
```

That gives me 3.141592653543740176758092275122180581093 when run on [Codepad](http://codepad.org/WJbnnD67).

As `double` should have *way* more than enough precision for basic calculations. If you need to compute millions of places, there isn't a standard floating point representation big enough to handle that.

Comment: trying to shoot the computer out of it's limits

Comment: It's not correct to say that "long double is not supported".  Rather, the Standard doesn't require it to have any more precision than just `double`.  But it absolutely is specified as part of the language, and required to support all the same operations as the other two floating-point types.  BTW, [there is no "ANSI C++"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5863051/103167) only ISO C++

Comment: error: 'setprecision' is not a member of 'std'|
what did i did wrong using code blocks

Comment: `long double is not supported in ANSI C++`. Huh?! It is absolutely supported, it is different from double for example on MinGW-w64 and it does provide one with better precision

Comment: My mistake. The compiler warning was: "Line 8: error: ISO C++ does not support 'long long'".

Comment: @SakhsModioths You need to include a library: #include <iomanip>

Answer (score 4):

If you really want more precision (not just display more decimal places), you could consider using the GMP (Gnu Multi-precision) Library.  You can specify the number of bytes to use for your doubles (8 bytes, 16 bytes, 32 bytes, 64 bytes, 128 bytes, ... ).  The library is usually used for cryto algorithms (that need really large integers).

https://gmplib.org/

You'll probably want to look at this similar thread: [C++ calculating more precise than double or long double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637621/c-calculating-more-precise-than-double-or-long-double?rq=1)

Comment: sorry can't vote with that reputation but i liked that

Comment: I upvote on your behalf, @SakhsModioths

Answer (score -1):

```
cout.precision(400);
  cout << pi << endl;
```

Comment: Be aware that this will print 400 digits, but most of them will be garbage bits (because an 8 Byte double won't contain that much precision).

Comment: Absolute best case scenario you get 323 "good" digits when using a 8 byte double.  But, in practice because of numerical issues you'll have far fewer accurate digits.

Comment: 400 is an example FPU of most cpus is 64bits those day (some opterons with 256bit)

Comment: Any representable floating point number (with 8 bytes) will look like M*2^e where e>= -1024 and M is an integer.  The smallest number you can therefore represent (positive number) is 1/2^1024 which has 323 decimal digits.